# Does React strip out the key property

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a snippet:

```
<StackPanel key="123">eureka</StackPanel>
```

When viewing this in the object inspector, I only see:

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:flex-start;align-items:flex-start" data-reactroot="">eureka</div>
```

But I see the key in the React tools.

Does react strip out the key property when viewing the generated HTML? I have seen a key property sometimes in the generated HTML, so I am unsure under what circumstances react chooses not to show it

Comment: Please be sure to search the docs first before asking on SO.

Comment: I know React uses keys to identify elements in a list. My question is different: does React strip out the keys for DISPLAY? I can see the key property in React tools, but not in the object inspector. My question is why? Please understand the question before down-voting

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429#issuecomment-61008642

Comment: I am able to get the key with:
        if (typeof child === "object") {
            if (child.key)
                 key = child.key.toString()

Comment: Again, my question is only about display, not access to the key

Comment: @prmph Sorry, I misread your question. I answered below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, React uses the key property internally to identify unique elements in a list, so it is stripped out of the final HTML.

`key` is not a valid HTML property on most elements, so leaving it in would be invalid. Also, the key itself could be on a React component instead of on an actual HTML element, so in that case it could not be passed through.